# Azure - cannot run image from private azure repository

Tags: azure, docker, containers

I have prepared a simple docker image based on java, which should calculate all Fibonacci numbers for given as arguments. `dockerfile` looks like below

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk15:jre-15.0.2_7-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE
ENV JAR_FILE=$JAR_FILE

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT  [\
  "java",\
  "-jar",\
  "/app.jar"\
]
```

Then I successfully pushed produced image to the azure resource, I can list it when I want to create an azure instance
[image]

I also pass as a `CMD` some args like `["1","5","14"]` which for the image should calculate fibo numbers and output them to the stdout. However, when I create & run the image (restart policy - never), after a while, I receive the following error:

```json
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InaccessibleImage",
      "message": "The image 'matcza2registry.azurecr.io/fibonacci:latest' in container group 'fibo-example' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or did not do? Thanks!

Comment: Do you choose the Azure Container Registry from the list it gives? And the same does the images?

Comment: As you see on the image, these fields are of type select.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, it seems the image name and tag are all right. So the possible reason is that you do not enable the admin user for the Azure Container Registry:

[image]

So you can check it and enable the admin user, then try again.

Comment: I needed to enable it before I uploaded image to the registry, but thanks.

Comment: @WitoldKupś Well, if it works for you please accept it.

Comment: I did not tell that it works, only that I already had it enabled, and it is not a solution.

Comment: @WitoldKupś Do you mean the error still exists?

Comment: Yes. Why it should change anything if I had this enabled even before I posted the issue there?

Comment: @WitoldKupś As I know, this issue only be caused by two reasons. One is using the wrong image tag, and another is the wrong credential. In the portal, it shows the image tag, so I think it's should not be the reason. Does the image can work well locally?

Comment: Of course it does. Tag is correct, access is also set, so it looks like there is also other option.

Comment: @WitoldKupś Do you try to deploy other images to take a test?

Comment: @WitoldKupś Any updates on this question? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I deployed.
No, I did not solve the problem - I gave up using azure for the thing I wanted, no more time for this issue.

Comment: @WitoldKupś OK.